# Please help python web automation selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to bypass google phone number verification to create a account? I have wrote some lines of Python code to make a google account... Is there any way to make a temp python phone number to receive messages like sms?

code

```py
ctr_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='view_container']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/button/span")
ctr_btn.click()
time.sleep(0.07)
myself_ctr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='view_container']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]")
myself_ctr.click()
ftr_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='firstName']")
ftr_name.send_keys("Anon")
lst_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lastName']")
lst_name.send_keys("Anon")
cng_email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='view_container']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/button/span")
cng_email.click()
email_txt_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']")
email_txt_box.send_keys(ran)
passwd_one = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='passwd']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
passwd_one.send_keys(passwd)
passwd_confirm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='confirm-passwd']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
passwd_confirm.send_keys(passwd)
next_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accountDetailsNext']/div/button/span")
next_form.click()
```

modules

```py
import os, sys, time
import base64
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import random
import string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be pretty hard to bypass phone verification using selenium.
You can create a temporary phone number using something like proovl.
For more info look at this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGoLbmQGimc

Answer (score 2):

There's no way no bypass that, except you create account on a clean browser, it will not ask you for phone number.